# Miva Select Orders From Database

Tags: database, select, ftp, miva

I have a client that is looking to create a batch order system that works with Miva.

I am wondering if anyone has created a system that exports orders created that day. The system we need to implement has to create a csv document and send the file to an ftp server.

If anyone has any ideas or examples I would greatly appreciate them as I have not yet worked with that part of Miva's system.

Edit:
After doing some research I found that miva's system saves the export file to the server which can be collected by ftp.  I can run the automation and file conversion from our localhost but

I need to find a module or create a module that can create that export daily. Does anyone know of an existing module.

Answer (score 0):

Miva doesn't have a native implementation of cURL.

But it does have, is a "Reports" area, where you can generate reports in CSV of orders placed within the last 24 hours.

It would be up to you to find a way to get the data from the export to the FTP server.

Depending on your setup, you can create a cron to do this for you, and use a different language to FTP the Miva generated CSV file to the proper server (that is, if it isn't the same as the Miva store is running on).